# How to edit pages after installing WP

Tags: customization

I'm really new to Wordpress. I just installed it following the instructions here 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP

and I'm wondering what to do next. I already have an account and a website set up, and how do I edit that website now on my computer?

any input would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from your description, its time to visit your localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/ and login